# Redirect all URLs starting with STRING that does NOT include a SUBSTRING

Tags: regex, .htaccess, redirect

I need some help with regex.

I'm building some 301 rules for an .htaccess

I need to redirect all urls starting with a specific string excluding one that has a given word in the match-all part

this is the simple rule I'm using:

```
/my/sample/url/(.*)
```

I need to edit the (.*) part to say: anything except if contains "foobar"

if contains "foobar" I need a different 301 rule

Comment: I tried also /my/sample/url/(?!foobar)(.*) but is not working

Answer (score 1):

This looks like is working:

```
^(?!.*foobar)/my/sample/url/(.*)
```

does anybody have a better solution?